# My clan keeps losing wars

Tags: clash-of-clans

My clan has lost more wars than we have won for a variety of reasons:

1. Some of us don’t know which one to attack.
2. We don't really have a good strategy. When we stay provisionally ahead, some will use the 2nd attack on high level opponents to get more loot. And we lose the war at last.
3. The communication is bad. Clan messages are often missed because many members are offline.

How do your clans deal with these or similar problems? (I can't imagine we are the only ones) How do you communicate strategy or advice to folks? How is participation ensured in your clan?

Any other advice much appreciated!

Comment: bro. i feel ya. join a new clan where people are active

Answer (score 11):

- **Scout out and allocate all the easy targets first** - Make sure the poorly defended bases are allocated first and to clan members who will be taking part. These are the easy pickings and therefore you **must** be getting 3 stars on each. They can be allocated to the weaker members of the clan as long as you know they're going to turn up and do the job.
- **Clan members should call targets on prep day and then only attack the targets they've called.** - That way you have an idea of who's going to attack who and it gives you a chance to say if you think their choice is a bad one.
- **Only allow clan members to attack realistic targets!**
- **Don't double up!** - i.e. only attack targets that haven't already been allocated or attacked unless the first attack only scored 0-1 stars and you are positive they can achieve 3 stars.
- **Kick those that don't comply to the house rules** - If members repeatedly ignore these rules; or don't turn up; or have a poor defence when they could easily do better then kick them out of the clan. Remember if you've got 50 clan members and only 50% of those are active you'll be matched against another 50 member clan and the likely hood is they'll have a higher percentage of active players than you. But if you kick out your inactive members then your active population will increase and you'll still be matched against a clan of a similar size.

**Other Options:**
You could also split attack day in to two. Only allowing the stronger members of your clan to attack on the second day and therefore ensuring the weaker members have chance to attack targets that are of equal ability. Then your stronger members can attack what's left which should be the stronger targets. Though this might not work as well if your clan is multi national due to time differences.

Answer (score 3):

Key steps to win clan wars~~

Low level clans -

1. Kick inactive members that do not join wars before the start of every war

   - being inactive means they don't attack for your clan war and has weak bases so you are down a player for each inactive you have.
2. Get members to do real attacks and not some barb archer

   - wasting attacks with cheap army when someone else can easily 3 star the base means all previous attacks are wasted and can be attempted elsewhere.
3. Set goals, low tier war is quite easy to 3 star every base, so the goal should be 3 starring on each single attacks.
4. Recruit active members only

   - same with the kick of inactive, if you gain active members you get more reliable players to attack in your clanwar since low lv is a battle of which clan being active.

finally if your clan has 80 total attacks as a low lv clan 65+ should be used at-least every war.

High level clans -

1. Have selected few high performing attacks get their reserved targets before war starts to prevent them 3 staring a base that has 2 attempts of 0 star and 1 star (2 wasted attacks)

   - if you have a few player that is really good at attacking, instead of letting them pick up stars after your normal player attacked you can let them pick a few base they think they have high chances of 3 staring and you can let your lesser players attack the easier bases and get more attempts to try and hog the same base and maybe one of them will get the 3..
2. Go over with members why they failed horribly and what they need to change.

   - fixing their attacking issues such as read where the traps are, offset some giant bombs before attacking or simple as baiting cc/hero, and the HOW to bait it ect can improve them if they learn to listen and learn..
3. Only hardcore army allowed, TH9 most be hogged (might not be the case with new update) and TH10 must be attacked with hog | gowiwi/gowpe | dragon

   - in high level wars most th 9 will get 3 star and th10 will get 2 stars on them, so to match the pace of enemy's stars you need to set the same goal and get the stars in a high success rate armies.
4. set goals- Enemy TH9 - 3 star ALL \ TH10 - 2 star + all
5. Kick inactive players and those that do not know how to attack

   - when they are really really bad or just keep using barb archers to 50% bases or uses ballion as an army which is obviously not going to work in high teir, you just need to tell them they don't fit in the clan and needs to go.

Comment: I've cleaned up your answer a bit, but there's not much else I can do.  Can you try to flesh out your answer a bit more, and add in why these steps help?

Comment: @Frank well some of them should be easy to understand imo.. but heres the reason why.

Answer (score 2):

Our Clan Carolina Panthers, has a leader that has all our emails, we get updates, charts and our war plan is written in stone. We attack in groups. 1-5 6-10 11-15 and so on.... you can attack anyone in your group the first 12 hrs afer that you are fee to attack anyone 1-50. This gives the little base a chance.. we have had the same guys for over 6 months since we started... This says it all.. we win 90 % of the time. We also have a sister clan  #1 Cardiac cats that anyone has to go there first to be screened in case we need a player in war. If someone is sick and can't make the war they go there and we replace them with a temp. Our main clan cango there as well if they want to war more than we do then come back to the main clan in time for out main war.    Out leader is the best with spreadsheets and keeps us informed on our stats etc....

Comment: Wow - this is serious clashing! Impressive commitment.

Answer (score 1):

In our clan we call our first attack on prep day. Bases have to be either 10 above or 10 below the persons cw base. This is to give all members a base that they can win on. The bottom 5 bases are assigned to the bottom five members automatically. We hold bases for those who called them 12 hours then people can attack any base with in the 10-10 rule. Second attacks must stay within the 10-10 rule and must need stars. People who go for loot not stars are kicked. People who don't use at least one of their attacks are kicked unless they have told us before hand. Only our highest troops are put in clan castles. If you get though and keep kicking people who don't follow the rules you'll end up with a great clan.

Answer (score 0):

We, at 177b, were on a losing streak as well but we figured out the problem. We noticed that whenever there is a gap between the experience levels of the top 5 players and the other members, the war became exponentially tougher(literally). We then filled the gap with more players and were able to win even more wars and all of us are able to attack successfully. Just a note of caution - don't include inactive players in the war. Also, including a low level player brings down the toughness. Happy clashing!